# Inserting into table Postgres 9.4 vs 9.1

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.4

My team is thinking of switching from 9.1 to 9.4 and as a part evaluation we would like to measure how much of an improvement is `INSERT INTO TABLE ...` where there are `3-4` columns of fixed length types like `INT`, `DOUBLE PRECISION`. We are using an unbatched `INSERT` and the tables are `logged` and `not temporary`. `fsync` is set to `on`.

**Q0**: Are there any grounds to think that `9.4` would be faster than `9.1` on this particular statement?

For example based on improved WAL performance:

https://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/features.pdf

Clearly the best answer would be to go and check our data and put an experiment, but lets allow some speculation.

**Q1**: Are there performance evaluations that you are aware of?

**Q2**: How much of `INSERT` is taken by `WAL`?

### Settings on the server (copied verbatim from `9.1` config file)

```
#fsync = off
#synchronous_commit = on
#wal_sync_method = fsync
#full_page_writes = on
#wal_buffers = -1
#wal_writer_delay = 200ms

shared_buffers = 15GB
temp_buffers = 1024MB
work_mem = 1024MB
```

Comment: Remove all doubt and all opinion: install 9.4, build a couple of test schemas, and measure performance.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' totally agree, but its important to know why might there be an improvement, before even starting to think of switching to a new version. There are enough parameters to tune and doing a "search" for optimal configuration is sometimes impossible in production due to time and other constraints.

Answer (score 3):

The link you provided is based on information found in [Section E.2.3.1.2. General Performance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/release-9-4.html) - a great read by the way. Based on your suggested test, I would not expect any real performance difference because you will not take advantage of parallel or partial writes (regarding wal files). That said, you might run across this in the future. Also, 9.4 (well, post 9.1 really) provides many useful tools and performance enhancements that, in my opinion, justify a switch from 9.1 to 9.4. For instance, since 9.2, JSON is now a datatype, Index Only scans are possible, and in-memory sorting has been improved by as much as 25%. 9.3 saw the introduction of materialized views (with concurrent refresh in 9.4) and updatable "simple" (definition expanded slightly in 9.4) views. In 9.4, aggregates are enhanced and ALTER SYSTEM defined (the ability to change config settings (goes into postgresql.auto.config which is read last, ensuring it overrides postgresql.config values) using a SQL command).

Of note, default logging has also changed. For instance, when creating a table, you won't receive messages about implicit index and sequence creation (set log level to DEBUG1 to fix - drove me crazy though when I switched from 9.1 to 9.3, especially during lectures).

In regards to question 1, I'd run a [TPC](http://www.tpc.org/information/current_specifications.asp) benchmark test (C and VMS are the only ones that aren't free). For question 2, that really depends on your wal settings, but with what I see from your config file, it shouldn't matter in regards to version performance. I'd also run pgtune on your system (link below) to ensure your config file is as optimal as possible before testing.

As with the other commenters, just build it out and see what happens. You might not get much, if any, difference with straight inserts, so I'd try large, multi-table joins, huge sorts, and lots of transaction simulation (e.g., lots of inserts, updates, and deletes - just use plpgsql for simplicity) - the TCP queries will also do a pretty good job of performance testing.

Links:

To find the "What's new" PostgreSQL wiki pages, add the version number to the end of the following [URL](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.#version#).

You can find a GUI version of pgtune at pgtune.leopard.in.ua; the standalone download is hit or miss from pgfoundry because it always seems to be down.